# Which version of an image is my container running?

Tags: rancher

I have a container running in Rancher in a host I don't have shell access to.

I can see on the web interface that it is running a `org/image:tag` image, but I want to know if the current version of that tag on Docker Hub is the same as the one it is running on my host.

**How can I ask Rancher for the image's version/ID?**

Locally, I would get that output by running `docker images`, seeing the `Image ID` column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running rancher 1.x, you can use the `docker` subcommand of the rancher cli.

For example, use `rancher ps` to get the host ID of your service:

```
$ rancher ps stack/service
ID         NAME        IMAGE                  STATE     HOST      IP            DOCKER         DETAIL
1i210290   service-1   example/image:latest   running   1h886     10.42.54.91   5f7325b162d2
```

Then use the HOST and DOCKER id's to inspect using

```
$ rancher --host 1h886 docker inspect --format '{{.Image}}' 5f7325b162d2
sha256:649dcb69b782d4e281c92ed2918a21fa63322a6605017e295ea75907c84f4d1e
```

If you are running rancher 2.x, use the `rancher kubectl` form:

```
$ rancher kubectl get po mypod-748bb48975-qbcqd -o jsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[*].imageID}'
docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:1c1904acacb3c494df70c578ec777b0fb7b2b7d1e45d01f447396d1a7302d967
```